# How do I upload to cdnjs?

Tags: javascript, cdn

How do I upload to cdnjs? I have no clue and no experience with git.

I have a file that I want to upload to cdnjs. Do I have to download something.
Can someone walk me through what I have to do?

Answer (score 22):

You can't just "upload" a single file to cdnjs.

Read [CDNJS contributing document](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), in particular, for library [even to be considered](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#b-request-a-new-library):

> - [...] please make sure it's not a personal project, we have a basic requirement for the popularity, like 100 stars on GitHub or 500 downloads/month on npm registry.
> - The new library must have at least one officially public accessable repository and open source license.

When you have that covered, you can [create a pull request](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#b-pull-request) for your library to be included in [cdnjs's master GitHub repo](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/).